# How to recover contents of an external hard drive with a corrupted partition table?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, data-recovery

I have a WD Elements 5TB USB hard drive that `fdisk -l` now shows as a single partition of Microsoft basic data:

```
Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1   2048 9767473151 9767471104  4.6T Microsoft basic data
```

The last time I used it it contained 2 partitions in NTFS format as supplied by the manufacturer.

I have no clue as to what corrupted the partition table, but possibly the data is still present on the disk and can be recovered. Can anyone advise me as to procedure to follow, linux tools to do this?

Comment: “The last time I used it it contained 2 partitions in NTFS format as supplied by the manufacturer.” The last time you used it was when? What OS were you using on the system the drive was connected to? You mention Linux here but NTFS is Windows. Are you attempting to read a Windows NTFS formatted drive in Linux? That might be the core issue here; not data corruption.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 NTFS support on linux has come a long way and even the kernel driver is pretty solid these days. Apart from that, linux should have no problem identifying a drives partition layout at all as that has nothing to do with the filesystem.

Comment: I don't remember the partition sizes, system is Lubuntu 20.04.  I understand you can use dd to copy a fs, but that would entail buying another 5T HD, which I would prefer to avoid. /dev/sda1 itself is undamaged, other usb devices mount on it without trouble. What I have in mind is this: On the device there is a directory tree of the files it contains. Is there any way of recovering that tree, from which I should be able to figure out the partition sizes, and then use cgdisk to recreate the partition table. Would changing the partition table damage the data on the disk?

Comment: Changing the partition table would result in a full loss of your data. If you have valuable data on the drive, do not attempt anything without a full backup of the disk. `testdisk` might be an option, but do not expect too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Testdisk from [www.cg-security.org](http://www.cg-security.org).

If you don't use legacy operating systems, make sure to set "GPT" in Testdisk.

MBR would only be required for use with a legacy operating system that does not understand GPT and assuming that your disk does not contain converting electronics showing a sector size of 4096 byte instead of 512 byte at the interface.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't actually have to use testdisk, but it referred me to ntfsfix, which did the job automatically.